# Format Timestamp with constant precision

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, timestamp

I'm trying to format a `TIMESTAMP` with 6 digits of the fractional part. `'FF'` seems to print all available digits, even if I explicitly declare a `TIMESTAMP(6)`:

```
DECLARE
  t  TIMESTAMP(6);
BEGIN
  t := SYSTIMESTAMP;
  dbms_output.put_line( TO_CHAR(t, 'FF') );
END;
```

prints
`912387000`

Is there a way to get
`912387`
instead (without using `SUBSTRING` or something similar)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes that's possible, by using 'FF6':

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     t  TIMESTAMP(6);
  3  BEGIN
  4     t := SYSTIMESTAMP;
  5     dbms_output.put_line( TO_CHAR(t, 'FF') );
  6     dbms_output.put_line( TO_CHAR(t, 'FF6') );
  7  END;
  8  /
234771000
234771

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Here is the link to the documentation: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements004.htm#r16c1-t64

Regards,
Rob.